# Are phytosanitary certificates needed to ship a plant within a state?

Tags: pest-control, plant-health

Apparently my state, California, has stricter restrictions of shipping plants. Many online nurseries say that I must pay extra money for a phytosanitary certificate to ship to California or else the plant may be rejected by the post office. Are phytosanitary certificates only necessary when crossing state lines or are they also necessary interstate? I live in Northern California and want to buy plants from a nursery in Southern California. I'm wondering if they can legally ship the plants to me without paying for the certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A phytosanitary certificate should only be necessary when plants are shipped between states or countries.  I've never heard of one being required to ship inside a state.  However, you can always call the nursery to confirm that they don't need one to ship your order inside the state of California.

Comment: It is really hard to communicate with this nursery - the guy barely speaks English. I had already ordered a Wax Apple tree from this nursery before I learned about phytosanitary certificates. It shipped to me on schedule. The security was either lax or the certificate just isn't necessary interstate. I'm thinking of getting more trees from this nursery because my Wax Apple looked pretty sturdy.

Comment: I'm about 99% sure that they aren't required in-state. Another place you might be able to get the definitive answer on this is your local Agricultural Extension agency.